# Android Room - Many-to-many relationship not returning relation entities

Tags: android, many-to-many, android-room

I've followed the documentation provided on [android developer guides](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#many-to-many) and [a Medium article](https://medium.com/coding-blocks/handling-many-to-many-relationship-in-android-addb60a3a3).

I'm trying to return a playlist of songs, but want a list of entities and not just the IDs. Following the above links I have this.

My Entities:

```
@Entity
data class MediaEntity(
    @PrimaryKey val identifier: String,
    val imageUrl: String,
    val title: String,
    val description: String,
    val media: String,
    val duration: Double,
    val progress: Int,
    val listenedToCompletion: Boolean
)

@Entity
data class PlaylistEntity(
    @PrimaryKey val playlistId: String,
    val playlistName: String,
    val playlistDescription: String = "",
    val currentPosition: Int = 0
)

@Entity(primaryKeys = ["playlistId", "identifier"])
data class PlaylistMediaLinkEntity(
    val playlistId: String,
    val identifier: String
)
```

My DAO for the link table is as follows:

```
@Dao
interface PlaylistMediaLinkDao {

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM PLAYLISTENTITY")
    fun getPlaylistWithMediaItems(): List<MediaInPlaylist>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(playlistMediaLinkEntity: PlaylistMediaLinkEntity)


}
```

And then my media in playlist object:

```
class MediaInPlaylist() {
    @Embedded
    lateinit var playlist: PlaylistEntity

    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "playlistId",
        entity = MediaEntity::class,
        entityColumn = "identifier",
        associateBy = Junction(
            value = PlaylistMediaLinkEntity::class,
            parentColumn = "playlistId",
            entityColumn = "identifier"
        )
    )
    lateinit var mediaEntities: List<MediaEntity>
}
```

I can confirm my PlaylistMediaLinkEntity is populated with playlist-media id pairs, but when calling `getAllPlaylistsWithMediaItems`, the `MediaInPlaylist` object is returned with the `Playlist` data, but the list of `mediaEntries` is empty.

Have I left something out or where am I going wrong? What I've done matches most examples online.

Comment: Can you find any solution? I faced this problem like you, but after 9 month :)

Comment: have you found any solution for this case?